# How to throttle Photostream traffic?

Tags: photos.app, network, photo-stream

When my wife's 2012 macbook pro is doing it's photostream sync, it slows my internet connection to a crawl and gives me 500+ pings in various video games.

If I knew the ports that Photostream uses, I could set up a QOS rule on my DD-WRT router- what ports does it use?

Another possible solution, is there a setting in IPhoto or the photostream agent to tell it to stop using all available bandwidth to sync?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It uses port 443.

It is the default port for HTTPS, though, so it will affect a lot of other applications and services other than PhotoStream.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. I've added QOS rules to boost priority for games where I'm seeing issues, but this is a tedious work-around. I have no idea how apple thinks that using all available bandwidth (and not providing options to alter this behavior) for something as low priority as photo-syncing is good network citizenship.